# Update BIOS Acer Travelmate 4750g

Tags: bios, acer-travelmate

I was trying to install a Linux Distro but I couldn't proceed. Someone suggested to update the BIOS but after downloading the BIOS file from Acer website and running the windows version of it my laptop shuts down and the BIOS version stays the same, v1.19.
I searched in the internet but I couldn't find the precise method of updating BIOS for my laptop. And because there was some bricked BIOSes I was reluctant to do it. Is there a way to update BIOS without ruining my laptop?

BIOS Brand: Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
Current BIOS version: 1.19
Downloaded BIOS version: 1.23
Downloaded from: [acer website](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3626?b=1)

Errors:

```
2019-10-27 12:53:56   InitWmi No method existence be found
2019-10-27 12:53:56   INT 15h failed in EcramWriteByte
```

Comment: If the BIOS refuses to install then it is the wrong version.

Comment: @harrymc Well I have downloaded it from Acer website. The version is 1.23 and my current BIOS version is 1.19. You say I should install every updated version after 1.19 one by one?

Comment: That's no necessary. I think that it does not fit your hardware if it doesn't install. You could perhaps [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1496365/edit) your post with the details of the BIOS and where you downloaded it from, and any error message that you might have.